# Scaling Activity's layout to fit the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have the layout on my `LoginActivity`, in which I have (in the following order, top to bottom): logo, horizontal line, two `EditText`'s, OK/login `Button`, and `TextView`. My problem is that on smaller screens, the logo is too big compared to the screen size and some of the elements are on the bottom, not visible on the screen (although the `ScrollView` works).

I would like to change my layout so that is scales to fit the screen (preferably: scaling logo **and** all the other elements proportionally but scaling only the logo would be enough). How do I do that?

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_header_selector"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_login"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edit_login"
                android:layout_below="@id/edit_login"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_form_login"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pass_login"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/loginactivity_password_text_hint"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_grey"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/edit_password"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="Image"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_ok_login" />

            <!-- Horizontal line -->

            <View
                android:id="@+id/hr2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/button_login"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_app_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_login"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
                android:text="SOME INFO TEXT"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:contentDescription="Image"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/app_logo_login" />

            <!-- Horizontal line -->

            <View
                android:id="@+id/hr1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/hr1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_form_login"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_tel_login"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/loginactivity_login_text_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_grey"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you can also try to have different images for different screen resolutions and put them in your respective drawable folders. This will also work

Comment: I have different images for different screen resolutions but in some cases it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` instead of `Framelayout`. And set the orientation as horizontal.
And then put all other views such as textview, edittext and imageview's `android:layout_width=0px` and `android:layout_width=1`.

Comment: you can combine both of your answers and seperate them with "or". Just asking, there is no need for two answers on same post. Thats what i feel. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow through this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It has everything explained for normal app development.

Answer (score 0):

```
or try like this>>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orienation="horizontal" >



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_password"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_login"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edit_login"
            android:layout_below="@id/edit_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_form_login"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_pass_login"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/loginactivity_password_text_hint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_grey"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:typeface="normal" />
            .....


</LinearLayout>
```